# Only run tests if a variable is larger than a value Cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, end-to-end

I am trying to only run a set of tests if the version is a certain number or higher in cypress, however I can't seem to make it work correctly. The code below is a bit of an abstraction but shows the overall structure:

```
if (version < 8203) {
  context('Skipping Tests', () => {
    it('Feature Not Available', () => {
      cy.task('log', "Skipping test. Feature not available in this version");
    });
  });
else {
  context('Testing Feature', () => {
    it('Test 1', () => {

    });
    it('Test 2', () => {

    });
    it('Test 3', () => {

    });
  });
}
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way to go about this and I have tried several different ways to structure this including putting the if statement in the context but it looks like cypress ignores the if statement or just moves on to the last context and it function.

Comment: Are you sure `version` is defined and contains the value you expect?

Comment: Well, you have shown the comparison the wrong way round. How is it in the actual test?

Comment: @Ackroydd Ah, sorry. Yes the skip test should be in the first block. Sorry I mixed up the structure as I have been trying different ways to make it work. That being said when it is the correct way it still doesn't work.

Comment: @CalebMiller yes I am sure, I ahve it printong to console and it is parsed as an Int. ```let version;
getVersion((setVersion) => {
  version = parseInt(setVersion.replace(/[v.]/g, ''));
  console.log(version); //8203
});```

Comment: Now there's a syntax error (missing closing bracket for `if {`) but with that fixed, and with `version === 8203`, the `else` branch of your code should run. If it's still not working as expected for you, keep checking your assumptions about the full code you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention this code for obtaining the value in `version`.

```js
let version; 
getVersion((setVersion) => {   
  version = parseInt(setVersion.replace(/[v.]/g, ''));   
  console.log(version); //8203 
});
if (version < 8203) {  ??? is this where you test ???
```

If the above pattern is how your test looks, I'd say the `getVersion()` callback has not completed before the `if()` is evaluated.

Does this structure improve things?

```js
let version; 
getVersion((setVersion) => {   
  version = parseInt(setVersion.replace(/[v.]/g, ''));   
  console.log(version); //8203 

  if (version < 8203) {  
    ...
  }
  else {
    context('Testing Feature', () => {
      it('Test 1', () => {
      ...
    });
  }
});
```